# PHP api call with CURL and authentication

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I got this code:

```
    // service
    $url = 'https://services.daisycon.com/publishers/' . $publisher_id  . '/news';

    // initialize curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set the http request authentication headers
    $headers = array( 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password ) );

    // set curl options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

    // execute curl
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // check http code
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // close curl resource
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($code == 200)
    {
        // json decode reponse
        $news = json_decode($response);

        // display response
        foreach ($news as $news_item)
        {
            echo 'id: ' . $news_item->id . "\n";
            echo 'name: ' . $news_item->title . "\n\n";
        }
    }
```

And used this [documentation](https://developers.daisycon.com/api/example-code/) and looked into this [authentication](https://developers.daisycon.com/api/authentication/).
But I can't get it to work, when I echo the code it shows 0.
I've filled in all my details. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
When I run this in console:

```
curl https://services.daisycon.com/publishers/{id}/news -u {username}:{password}
```

Then is works fine.
So How do I set that command into PHP code..?

Comment: Don't pass a second argument to curl_getinfo, instead do just: `$info = curl_getinfo($ch);` and then `var_dump($info);` and you'll get some more details that might help.

Comment: Can't really get any further with this info: https://pastebin.com/HckeWDsp

Comment: Works ok for me, I think maybe you've got some networking issues. Perhaps no DNS resolution or you're being blocked outbound. Can you do `curl --head https://services.daisycon.com/publishers/52957/news` from the command line?

Comment: @AlexHowansky thank you for trying to help, this is what I got as response: https://pastebin.com/fGJxUHus

Comment: Weird. What's your PHP version?

Comment: @AlexHowansky `5.6.19`, I think it that has something to do with the way I have to authenticate. Please take a look at: https://developers.daisycon.com/api/authentication/

Comment: Try giving it a bad user/pass. Do you get a 401?

Comment: @AlexHowansky no, still `[http_code] => 0`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky how do I set this command line to PHP: `curl https://services.daisycon.com/publishers/{id}/news -u {username}:{password}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) to check if there was an error with the curl operation, also you should check to see what HTTP code is being returned if it is not a 200 OK, if you are definitely received a 200 OK back then perhaps [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) your response variable to check that you receiving the desired data and that you are using the correct property names

What's below should help you to find out that the issue is

```
// service
$url = 'https://services.daisycon.com/publishers/' . $publisher_id  . 
'/news';

// initialize curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set curl options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL=> $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "accept: application/json",
        "authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($username.":".$password),
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json",
    ),
));

// execute curl
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($curl);

// check http code
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// close curl resource
curl_close($ch);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
else{
    if ($code == 200)
    {
        // json decode reponse
        $news = json_decode($response);

        // display response
        foreach ($news as $news_item)
        {   
            //checks if both properties are set
            if(isset($news_item->id,$news_item->title)){ 
                echo 'id: ' . $news_item->id . "\n";
                echo 'name: ' . $news_item->title . "\n\n";
            }
            //if not set...
            else{
                echo "Id Or Title Not Set\n";
                var_dump($news);
                echo "\n\n";
            }       
        }
    }
    //if not a 200 OK
    else{
         echo "Did Not Receive 200 OK\n";
         echo "Received Code:".$code."\n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the following errors: `Warning: curl_setopt_array(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource in file.php on line 48

Warning: curl_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in file.php on line 52
Did Not Receive 200 OK Received Code:0`

Answer (score 0):

maybe they switched from http basic auth to digest (a more secure method of transferring username/password), or any of the other auth methods supported by curl. but the fact that `curl https://services.daisycon.com/publishers/{id}/news -u {username}:{password}` works, means that it *IS* an auth method natively  supported by curl. why do you make the auth header yourself? that is difficult and error prone, you should just tell libcurl to login for you, like you tell curl (the cli program) to login for you.

```
$ch = curl_init();
if(!curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH=>CURLAUTH_ANY,
CURLOPT_USERPWD=>'username:password'
))){throw new \RuntimeException('curl_setopt_array failed. errno:'.curl_errno($ch).'. error:'.curl_error($ch);}
```

and, when debugging curl code, set a CURLOPT_STDERR and CURLOPT_VERBOSE, like

```
$debugh=tmpfile();
$debugf=stream_get_meta_data($debugh)['uri'];
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_STDERR=>$debugh,CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1));
...
//after curl_exec: 
$curldebugstr=file_get_contents($debugf);
var_dump($curldebugstr);
```

and in curl the cli program, use the `-v` argument. then you can compare the request that php-libcurl makes, with the request that the curl command line argument makes, what's their difference? it could ofc be that they do evil user agent detection, in which case, you can fake curl cli's useragent with CURLOPT_USERAGENT. also, if curl_setopt(_array) fails, it will return bool(false), you should make a wrapper function that checks if it returns false, and if it does, throw a runtime exception, with what argument failed to be set, and what curl_error() and curl_errno() reports, and use those wrappers.  - or at the very least, check the return each time you use the raw functions.

something like

```
function _curl_setopt_array($ch,array $arr){foreach($arr as $option=>$val){_curl_setopt($ch,$option,$val);}}
    function _curl_setopt($ch,int $option,$value){
            $ret = curl_setopt ( $ch, $option, $value );
            if (! $ret) {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException ( 'curl_setopt failed. errno: ' . curl_errno ($ch) . '. error: ' . curl_error ($ch));
            }
    }
```